# Large String while during POST ignores the letters after space

Tags: .net, php, html, css

I had a textarea, when i post that content in textarea, I only get only first word before a space is given. For example if my value in textarea is 'He is mad man', i get only 'He'.

plz Help me to sort out this problem;

Code:

```
<form name="SendSMS" method="post" action="admin_main.php">
                <div class="reg_item">Category </div>
                <div class="reg_item">
                    <select name="cat" class="reg_combo" class="tboxstyle">
                        <option value="car" class="tboxstyle">Carrer</option>
                        <option value="tho" class="tboxstyle">Thoughts</option>
                        <option value="jok" class="tboxstyle">Jokes</option>
                        <option value="hea" class="tboxstyle">Health</option>
                     </select>
                </div><br />


                <div class="reg_item">Message </div>
                <div class="reg_item"><input type="text" name="message" class="tboxstyle"></input></div><br />



                 <?
                            if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
                            {

                            $msms=new sms();
                            $msms->sendsms();


                            }

                         ?>


                <div class="reg_item"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Send >>" /></div>
                </form>
```

function:

```
function sendsms()
        {   
        try
            {

                                $cat              =$_POST[cat];
                $message      =$_POST[message];
                                $link="http://www.aswinanand.com/sendsms.php?uid=9488446874&pwd=sivad&phone=9952880550&msg=dg";
                $table="";

                if($cat=="car")
                {
                    $table=="carrer_memb";
                }
                elseif($cat=="tho")
                {
                    $table=="thoughts_memb";
                }
                elseif($cat=="jok")
                {
                    $table=="jokes_memb";
                }
                elseif($cat=="hea")
                {
                    $table=="health_memb";
                }



                $result = mysql_query("SELECT mobile FROM carrer_memb");

                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                     echo $message;
                                   $link="http://www.aswinanand.com/sendsms.php?uid=9488486874&pwd=sivakasi&phone=".$row['mobile']."&msg=".$message;
                                   $contents = file_get_contents($link);
                                   echo $contents;
                                   //header("Location: http://www.aswinanand.com/sendsms.php?uid=9488486874&pwd=sivakasi&phone=".$row['mobile']."&msg=".$message);


                                }



            }
        catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
        }








}
```

Comment: can we see your code? PHP or .NET or (PHP.NET)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to apply [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to all values in link string:

```
$params = array(
    'uid'  =>urlencode($uid),
    'pwd'  =>urlencode($pwd),
    'phone'=>urlencode($row['mobile']),
    'msg'  =>urlencode($message)
);
$link= 'http://www.aswinanand.com/sendsms.php?' . http_build_query($params)
```

P.S.
change your password, and never post your username and password online

Comment: You typed my answer faster than I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is 99.99% likely to be correctly POSTing the entire contents (use a firefox extension like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to be certain).  The problem is almost certainly in your server-side code that is parsing the HTTP request.  Any chance you could post that and explain a little bit more about your environment?